# adding listbox items and values showing it in different labels (between different forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

I want to add items and values from form 2 to form 3 Listbox and show it accordingly in the form 3 labels.Final product should look like this [form 2 adding the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnnkp.jpg) and [form 3 showing the value in menu and listbox accordingly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH7Ir.jpg)  
I can add one item like the product name but I also want to add other aspects like price. So when I click on listbox in form 3 ,it should only show the names but in labels it should show the price aspect.

Form 2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string getItem = NameTextBox1.Text;
        int getItem2 = Int32.Parse(PriceTxtBox2.Text);
        var f = new Form3(getItem, getItem2);
        f.Show();
    }
```

Form 3:

```
 public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {

    }
    public struct Menu1
    {
        public string foodname;
        public int foodprice;
    }

    public Form3(string title, int txt)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Menu1> menulist = new List<Menu1>();
        menulist.Add(new Menu1
        {
            foodname = title,
            foodprice = txt
        });


        foreach (Menu1 details in menulist)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(details.foodname));
            listBox1.Items.Add(details.foodprice);

        }
    }
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label4.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        label5.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: With this approach, you'll end up with many Form3 instances, all with only one entry.  Go the other direction, with Form3 having an "Add" button that creates an instance of Form2.  After Form2 is closed, retrieve the information from it and add it to the listbox...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you aren't connected to a database, which is highly recommended.

But following the way you want it, I guess you can either

1. Change your list box to a list view or data grid view that can have multiple columns then put your other details such as price and category in those columns then hide it leaving only the first column that has the product name visible to your user, then you can just retrieve the text in the hidden columns in your code to be displayed in the labels.
2. Have your list items in a form of a List, a multidimensional array etc(?) in a public static class (which is accessible to all and can keep track of all your added items from form 2 - although only in runtime unlike a database) then access it in your form 3 to fill your list box and get the other information such as price and category in the list like; get the index of the currently selected item then use that as index to access the list in the static class.